# Error in r for gls on corAR1-not unique

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to solve the problem with this error:

```
library(nlme)
gls(Number.of.Fish~Julian.Date+Temperature+Size.Class,na.action=na.omit,data=mydata,correlation=corAR1(form=~Julian.Date))

Error in Initialize.corAR1(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  covariate must have unique values within groups for "corAR1" objects
```

Answer (score 4):

You have two or more samples taken on the same `Julian.Date` and you can't have this in an `corAR1()` `corStruct()` object.

How you solve this will depend upon your sampling design. Are these values from two different sites? If so `site` should probably be in the `corAR1()`:

```
corAR1(form ~ Julian.Date | site)
```

Beyond that, I struggling to envision equally-spaced observations in time with two sample occurring on the same day.

If your response is a count, you might want to think again about using `gls()`, using a model for discrete count data instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately it is count data

Comment: There are ways to do this in the **mgcv** package. One is `bam()` which can fit a GAM with an AR(1) error model. Not sure how well this will deal with the duplicated observation. Otherwise you could use `gamm()` which fits via `glmmPQL()` in the MASS package and uses the correlation structures from **nlme**. Lastly, the `?magic` page (IIRC) includes an example of fitting assuming an AR(1) using `gam()` and some by hand fiddling.